# Rewrite Rule not works in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a problem with this redirect

```
RewriteRule ^games?game=MyGame$ /?noparams [R=301,L,QSA]
```

No logs but the redirect is not made. Btw this redirect works fine :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/gift$
RewriteRule (.*) /?noparams [R=301,L]
```

Can you help me please ? Thx in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: What URL is not redirecting with first rule?

Comment: @anubhava http://baseUrl.dev/games?game=MyGame

Comment: try ^/games?etc

Comment: the same.............

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteRule` cannot match a query string. You need to use a `RewriteCond` with `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^game=MyGame$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^games/?$ /?noparams [R=301,L,QSA,NC]
```